# SmartArray P400 Create Logical Drive Erase Data?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Does create logical drive on a Smart Array P400 erase existing data?

I have a disk that was from a RAID1 set on a IBM server. It's currently plugged in a HP server in order for me to read the data. Since P400 does not have JBOD feature, I am wondering if I just need to create a logical drive (e.g. RAID0) in order for the OS to recognize it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This will not work.

What are you expecting this to do? The IBM controller and the HP Smart Array controller have different on-disk RAID formats. As there is no passthrough or JBOD mode available on the HP controller, creating *any* logical drive, even a RAID0, will delete the existing data on the drive.